# check if all fields in object are null with Option

Tags: scala, option-type, avro

I have an java avro object with several fields. I want to check next condition:

- check if object is null
- check if all fields in object are null

Could you help me please how to do it with Option.

I tried this:

```
val employee = // init instance

Option(employee).filterNot(e => e.getName == null && e.getLastNamme == null && e.getId == null && ...)



@AvroGenerated
public class Employee extends SpecificRecordBase implements SpecificRecord {
    public Integer id;

    public List<Department> properties;

    public String name;

    public String lastName;

    …..
}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: How to write it without  e.getName == null && ....

Comment: if you want to check whether `getName` is null, then `e.getName == null` is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to check if something is `null`, `== null` (or perhaps `eq null`) is going to be the clearest way to express that (and it will be the most efficient to execute).

However, some Scala codebases (I've worked with them...) have style rules which forbid `null` (and the culture of the team may be reluctant to disable the linter in the cases (e.g. Java interop such as this) where `null` would otherwise be highly justifiable).

For these, there are a few options (pun?) to consider:

1. If the objection is to the literal `null`, then you can get around it by using `None.orNull`:

```
Option(employee).filterNot { e =>
  e.getName == None.orNull
  // etc.
}
```

For extra passive aggression to point out the absurd rigidity:

```
val nul = None.orNull

Option(employee).filterNot { e =>
  e.getName == nul
}
```

2. If either of those doesn't get past review, then the even less efficient, but more likely to satisfy a dogmatic "the value of `null` should never be summoned" rule, you can remember that:

- `filterNot(pred)` can generally be replaced (specifically for `Option`, but other monads that have a useful concept of emptiness) with
  `flatMap { a => if (pred(a)) None else Some(a) }`.
- `Option(x)` goes to `None` if `x` is `null`

```
Option(employee).flatMap { e =>
  Option(e.getName).map(_ => e)
}.flatMap { e =>
  Option(e.getLastName).map(_ => e)
}  // etc.
```

So much overhead, and so much cognitive load, but the devs who dominate your team culture might get to delude themselves that they're writing Haskell...